# Kong is not working for PUT and Delete methods

Tags: routes, kong, dynamic-routing

I'm using Kong as my API gateway. The routes actually work fine for GET and POST method but when it's about PUT and DELETE I always get the

`{ "message": "no Route matched with those values" }`

Here is the example i'm using for my routes:

**Request regarding all the data:**

```yaml
service:
 - name: Host.Data
    url: http://myhost.com/data
    routes:
      - name: Host.Data
        methods:
          - GET
          - POST
        paths:
          - /v1/myhost/data
```

**Request regarding an id:**

```yaml
- name: Host.DataById
    url: http://myhost.com/data/any
    routes:
      - name: Host.DataById
        methods:
          - GET
          - PUT
          - DELETE
        paths:
          - /v1/myhost/data/any
```

Answer (score 1):

The path parameter is a regex.
So `/v1/myhost/data` is matching `/v1/myhost/data/any`
You need to add `$` to have two distinct configuration

```yaml
service:
 - name: Host.Data
    url: http://myhost.com/data
    routes:
      - name: Host.Data
        methods:
          - GET
          - POST
        paths:
          - /v1/myhost/data$
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work for me.